# How to know when Shared Element Transition ends

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am working with `Shared Element Transitions` between activities. The transition is working fine but I want to know when the shared element transition ends so that I can show other things.

I tried using `onSharedElementEnd` in `SharedElementCallback` in the activity I am transition to but that gets called before the transition starts.

is there another callback i can listen for?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Did you try to bind animation listener to the shared element view inside `onMapSharedElements`? `ViewCompat.animate(view)` will give you either a new or cached `ViewPropertyAnimator(Compat)` and then binding the animation listener should be trivial. I haven't tried it, though.

```
setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
                super.onMapSharedElements(names, sharedElements);
                View keySharedElementView = sharedElements.get("keySharedElement");
                if(keySharedElementView != null){
                    ViewCompat.animate(keySharedElementView).setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListenerAdapter(){
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(view);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

What about adding `Transition.Listener` to the shared element transition?

```
 Transition sharedElementEnterTransition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
 sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter() {
         @Override
          public void onTransitionEnd(android.support.transition.Transition transition) {
                    super.onTransitionEnd(transition);
           }
      });
```

Comment: For anyone else wondering, the `TransitionListenerAdapter` is just an empty implementation of the `Transition.TransitionListener` interface. It is likely taken from a public project by @alex-lockwood : https://github.com/alexjlockwood/activity-transitions/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alexjlockwood/activity/transitions/TransitionListenerAdapter.java

Comment: @gnuf Adapter of interface is only to allow you to implement only the method you need. This is general for all listener adapters in android sdk and java. This will keep your code clean and neat.

Comment: what about fragments? both solution didn't works for me

Comment: @HugoGresse that's a good question. I'd like somebody to confirm this weird behavior: simple transition, fragmentA to fragmentB (v4). All I want to know is when transition is over. So I put a listener in fragmentB like: `((Transition) getSharedElementEnterTransition()).addListener()` which is never called. But! If I also add an empty listener to the same transition in fragmentA, then both listeners start working ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Here is the simple demo: https://github.com/Ghedeon/TransitionBug

Comment: Feel free to star the relevant issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225415

Comment: @Ghedeon have you tried call "addListener()" in "onAttach()" of the fragmentB?Like here:https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/e8c61e7e23f74aa6786696dad22e5136b423a334/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/session/SessionDetailFragment.java

Comment: I can approve that calling the getSharedElementEnterTransition() in onAttach works.
I can also approve that the listener's onTransitionEnd is not called in any other method and the workaround of @Ghedeon works

Comment: getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition() always return null to be me. any thing i am missing?

Comment: I tried the same code above and "onAnimationEnd(View view)"  method is not getting called!!!. Any reasons???

Comment: is there a way to add animation progress update listener?

Comment: How to make this to work for below Lollipop. Because current code requires Lollipop

Answer (score 20):

Please try `onEnterAnimationComplete()` callback on your activity.

I bet this is exactly what you ere looking for.

```
 @Override
    public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
        super.onEnterAnimationComplete();

    //your code 
    }
```

Comment: Looks great, but is any suggestion on how to use it with Fragment transitions?

Comment: how to use? i dont know

Comment: this solution works, until you find out that the method doesn't get called in api level less than kitkat, expected this to be called with support activity. Anyway a better option than all other methods

Comment: Note that this is called _before_ the shared element transition has finished.

Comment: This doesn't work well for me. It's called too early. Add logs and you'll see. What works is `getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().addListener()`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I do in a fragment:

```
Transition sharedElementEnterTransition = getActivity().getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
    sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: depending on what you want this is wrong. If you are starting your fragment transaction with a SharedElementTransition then you should call getSharedElementEnterTransition() directly without getActivity().getWindow() from your fragment - in onAttach()

Comment: Hi Nino, thanks for the comment. This fragment is not the starting of transaction, but an ending. Is this a good practice for ending? Thanks,

Comment: yes, I do it like this in my fragment. if fragmentA calls FragmentB then this would be in fragmentB.

Comment: It gets called for exit as well. why?

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling to do this in Kotlin using the navigation component but managed to get it working with this

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    setAndPostponeEnterAnimation()
    _binding = PokemonDetailFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    setInsets()
    handleNavigationArgs()
    return binding.root
}

private fun setAndPostponeEnterAnimation() {
    postponeEnterTransition()
    sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context)
        .inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transition)
    addSharedElementListener()
}

private fun addSharedElementListener() {
    (sharedElementEnterTransition as TransitionSet).addListener((object :
        TransitionListenerAdapter() {
        override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
            super.onTransitionEnd(transition)
            createRevealAnimation()
        }
    }))
}
```

so I can wait for the shared transition to finish before starting a new animation

Comment: not working for me and even get an exception: cannot be cast to TransitionSet

Comment: the import was andoirx.app, you mean I have to import from android.app ?

Comment: besides that, it seems that there is setEnterSharedElementCallback for handling onEnd but the functionality is not well

Comment: no i meant maybe a bad import for transition set

Answer (score 0):

Try to add TransitionListener on Fragment A, not B. And use `android.support.transition.Transition`

Fragment A

```
            val anim = DetailsTransition()
            anim.addListener(object : android.support.transition.Transition.TransitionListener
            {
                override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: android.support.transition.Transition) {
                }

                override fun onTransitionResume(transition: android.support.transition.Transition) {
                }

                override fun onTransitionPause(transition: android.support.transition.Transition) {
                }

                override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: android.support.transition.Transition) {
                }

                override fun onTransitionStart(transition: android.support.transition.Transition) {
                }

            })
```