# How to get the transition completion callback between fragments

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-bottomsheetdialog

So this question is similar: [How to know when enter transition ended on Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895039/how-to-know-when-enter-transition-ended-on-fragment)

---

But I do not set transition by myself and it's not a shared transition. So I can't get transition object for attaching my listeners.

---

Background:

I used BottomSheetDialogFragment, that under the hood using style with own transitions

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">
  @style/Animation.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog
</item>
<style name="Animation.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog" parent="Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/mtrl_bottom_sheet_slide_in</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/mtrl_bottom_sheet_slide_out</item>
</style>
```

And what I wanted is add my animation after completion of transition. Since playing animation simultaneously with transition is useless