# Detecting when shared element transition has finished

Tags: android, callback, element, transition, shared

I need to know when does a shared transition finishes between activities.

I have ActivityA and ActivityB and I have tried `setLayoutAnimationListener`, `setEnterSharedElementCallback`, `setExitSharedElementCallback`, `onEnterAnimationComplete` and every answer in [How to know when Shared Element Transition ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641752/how-to-know-when-shared-element-transition-ends) in the ActivityB

In any case, I have my shared element transition working, but the callbacks are called when the animation is started and not when it has finished.

Comment: take an arbitary **handler** and delay it for say `300 ms` i think that will work well :)

Comment: see `Transition.TransitionListener`